# Cfquery not working, code and returned error attached

Tags: cfml, coldfusion-11

```
<cfquery name="info" datasource="users" result="data1">
     SELECT * FROM dbo.user
     ORDER BY fname
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#data1#">
<cfabort>
```

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/practice/index.cfm: line 3
1 :
2 :
3 :

Comment: The query looks correct, though did you try removing `dbo.`?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried it by using the name of table   From dbo.user TO dbo.testtable  and it worked well.